# How to insert a TikZ file into beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I use TikZiT https://sourceforge.net/projects/tikzit/ to get a graph file named `test.tikz`. How could I insert this graph into `beamer`?
For example, if I have an `abc.png` picture, then

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{abc.png}
\end{figure}
```

will insert the picture `abc.png` into a frame. Can I do the same thing for `.tikz` file? What codes do I need? And how do I add some mathematical formula around the graph in the `.tikz` file?

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Graph}

\input{test.tikz}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It also does not work if I copied codes from TikZiT and pasted into Latex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
\node [style=none] (0) at (-5.75, 4.5) {};
\node [style=none] (1) at (-7.75, 2) {};
\node [style=none] (2) at (-3.75, 2.25) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
\draw [style=arrow, in=132, out=-48, looseness=1.00] (0.center) to (2.center);
\draw [style=newstyle, in=4, out=-176, looseness=1.00] (2.center) to (1.center);
\draw (0.center) to (1.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Never used `tikzit`, but have you  tried `\input{test.tikz}`? Most likely it containts 'nothing' else than pure code with a `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` statement

Comment: Yes, but when compiling, lots of errors occur for the file test.tikz. And I used \usepackage{tikz} and \usepackage{filecontents}. I am wondering if I miss something.

Comment: you wouldn't normally use `figure` with beamer (you are not likely to want floats in a presentation)

Comment: it would be a lot easier to answer if you added to your question the generated file and a small wrapper beamer file and showed the error message. Then anyone can debug without having the generation tool.

Comment: Did you include all necessary TikZ libraries?

Comment: @Skillmon No. May I know which TikZ libraries are necessary?

Comment: How should I know without seeing some code? I can't guess (and I don't know TikZ that well, but another one might know, if he sees the generated TikZ code).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just added the codes.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems:

- `\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}`, `\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}` and `\pgfsetlayers{nodelayer,edgelayer}` is missing
- all the styles you use are undefined. As I have no idea how the finished picture should look like, I removed them. If some features like colour or line widths are missing, you have to define appropriate styles.
- you don't need `\usepackage{color}` with beamer, as beamer already loads `xcolor`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}


\definecolor{myfunnycolour}{RGB}{255,0,0}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlayers{nodelayer,edgelayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
\node (0) at (-5.75, 4.5) {};
\node (1) at (-7.75, 2) {};
\node (2) at (-3.75, 2.25) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
\draw [myfunnycolour,in=132, out=-48, looseness=1.00] (0.center) to (2.center);
\draw [in=4, out=-176, looseness=1.00] (2.center) to (1.center);
\draw (0.center) to (1.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, you have beaten me by seconds only...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry :)

Comment: The TikZ force is strong in you! Most Impressive ;-)

Comment: Yes. I changed the color of some edges in TikZiT, that is probably the reason why there are "newstyle" things after \draw. How can I change color of edges, if I know RGB of a color? And how can I add some arrows indicating the transformation from a graph to another? And how can I add some math formulae around edges?

Comment: @Connor Comments are not the place to ask new questions - but as I am in a good mood I added an example how to change colour.